# Pythonic equivalent of ./foo.py < bar.png

Tags: python, unit-testing

I've got a Python program that reads from `sys.stdin`, so I can call it with `./foo.py < bar.png`. How do I test this code from within another Python module? That is, how do I set stdin to point to the contents of a file while running the test script? I don't want to do something like `./test.py < test.png`. I don't think I can use [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html), because the input is binary, and I only want to handle a single file. The file is opened using `Image.open(sys.stdin)` from [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generalise your script so that it can be invoked from the test script, in addition to being used as a standalone program. Here's an example script that does this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys

def read_input_from(file):
    print file.read(),

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        # filename supplied, so read input from that
        filename = sys.argv[1]
        file = open(filename)
    else:
        # no filename supplied, so read from stdin
        file = sys.stdin
    read_input_from(file)
```

If this is called with a filename, the contents of that file will be displayed. Otherwise, input read from stdin will be displayed. (Being able to pass a filename on the command line might be a useful improvement for your `foo.py` script.)

In the test script you can now invoke the function in `foo.py` with a file, for example:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import foo

file = open("testfile", "rb")
foo.read_input_from(file)
```

Answer (score 2):

- Your function or class should accept a stream instead of choosing which stream to use.
- Your `main` function will choose `sys.stdin`.
- Your test method will probably choose a `StringIO` instance or a test file.

The program:

```
# foo.py
import sys
from PIL import Image

def foo(stream):
  im = Image.open(stream)
  # ...

def main():
  foo(sys.stdin)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The test:

```
# test.py
import StringIO, unittest
import foo

class FooTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_foo(self):

    input_data = "...."
    input_stream = StringIO.StringIO(input_data)
    # can use a test file instead:
    # input_stream = open("test_file", "rb")

    result = foo.foo(input_stream)
    # asserts on result

if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

A [comp.lang.python post](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/b642ba9f5a152a13) showed the way: Substitute a StringIO() object for sys.stdout, and then get the output with `getvalue()`:

```
def setUp(self):
    """Set stdin and stdout."""
    self.stdin_backup = sys.stdin

    self.stdout_backup = sys.stdout
    self.output_stream = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = self.output_stream

    self.output_file = None


def test_standard_file(self):
    sys.stdin = open(EXAMPLE_PATH)
    foo.main()
    self.assertNotEqual(
        self.output_stream.getvalue(),
        '')


def tearDown(self):
    """Restore stdin and stdout."""
    sys.stdin = self.stdin_backup
    sys.stdout = self.stdout_backup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always monkey patch Your `stdin`. But it is quite ugly way. So better is to generalize Your script as Richard suggested.

```
import sys
import StringIO

mockin = StringIO.StringIO()
mockin.write("foo")
mockin.flush()
mockin.seek(0)

setattr(sys, 'stdin', mockin)

def read_stdin():
    f = sys.stdin
    result = f.read()
    f.close()
    return result

print read_stdin()
```

Also, do not forget to restore `stdin` when tearing down your test.