# Unit testing keypresses and terminal output in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

If you search Google or SO for 'unit test stdin stdout python' you will find very many questions, each and every one of which is answered in one way or another with

> Do you really need to unit test Python's builtin `input` / `sys.stdin` methods?

My answer is *yes*, I emphatically do, because I'm essentially implementing my own `input` + poor-man's `libreadline` / `libcurses`, and I need to test using stdin and the contents of the terminal.

I happen to use a Unix-derived OS so I have pipes `|` and shell redirection `<`, so I could write a little shell script to do this alongside some Python helper code, and to test the terminal's actions (ANSI escape sequences, cursor movement, exactly what gets printed, etc) I could read from a known `/dev/tty/whatever`, but there are two main reasons I don't want to do this:

1. Testing code should be as cross-platform as the code it's testing (and not so fragile!)
2. I quite like `unittest`, thank you, and I don't want to resort to shell scripting and unix hackery (as much as I like unix hackery) just to test my module.

There must be a better way to test things like `curses`, not when you're *using* `curses` but when you're *developing* a `curses`.

---

Since it was requested, here's some examples of what I'm looking to test: ([full code on github](https://github.com/catb0t/input_constrain))

```
def _Getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch

class xyctl:
    def _terminal_size():
        import fcntl, struct
        h, w, hp, wp = struct.unpack('HHHH',
            fcntl.ioctl(0, termios.TIOCGWINSZ,
            struct.pack('HHHH', 0, 0, 0, 0)))
        return w, h, w * h

    def _matrix_calc(adj_x, adj_y):
        cur_x, cur_y = xyctl.getter()
        new_x, new_y = (
            (cur_x + adj_x),
            (cur_y + adj_y)
        )

        if (new_x * new_y) < (xyctl._terminal_size()[2]):
            return new_x, new_y
        else:
            _writer(CHAR_BEL)

    def getter():
        _writer(CHAR_ESC + "[6n")
        pos = until("R", raw=True)
        _writer(CHAR_CRR + CHAR_SPC * (len(pos) + 1) + CHAR_CRR)
        pos = pos[2:].split(";")
        pos[0], pos[1] = int(pos[1]), int(pos[0])
        return pos

    def setter(new_x, new_y):
        _writer(CHAR_ESC + "[{};{}H".format(new_x, new_y))

    def adjust(adj_x, adj_y):
        new_x, new_y = xyctl._matrix_calc(adj_x, adj_y)
        xyctl.setter(new_x, new_y)
```

Comment: @downvoter/s `please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved`

Comment: Can you give a specific (maybe dumbed down to be simple enough) example of a code snipped you'd like to test? It can probably be done by mocking or stubbing `input` or `sys.stdin`, so that you don't test the builtin functions, but instead test what your code does with them.

Comment: @das-g I've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late to the party here, but: I'm in exactly this situation, wanting to test the actual user-facing portions of the CLI, to be able to (i) ensure consistent behavior resulting from a given set of user keypresses, and (ii) inspect the actual content printed to console.

I put together a couple of classes that achieve this in (what seems to me) a pretty nice way, originally implemented [here](https://github.com/bskinn/sphobjinv/blob/5c5f43199c08594807a8b53ab2dd9a705478a1b1/sphobjinv/test/sphobjinv_base.py#L185-L251) and, as of this writing, now published in v1.0 pre-release on PyPI as [stdio-mgr](https://pypi.org/project/stdio-mgr/).  Most of it isn't especially novel, just a context manager to mock `stdout`/`stderr`/`stdin` over to temporary streams, as already described in answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3948399/4376000), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36491341/4376000) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571630/4376000).

The big difference from anything I've seen elsewhere is that `stdin` is mocked to a [custom `StringIO` subclass](https://github.com/bskinn/stdio-mgr/blob/b424a169d9e584115b8f90a28e99497aeeb93a26/stdio_mgr/stdio_mgr.py#L36-L72) which (a) automatically tees everything read from the stream over to the mocked `stdout`, and thus echoes the "typed input" to the "console"; and (b) implements an `.append()` helper method to allow addition of more content to the end of mock-`stdin` without changing the seek position.

Example usage:

```py
>>> from stdio_mgr import stdio_mgr
>>> with stdio_mgr() as (in_, out_, err_):
...     print('foobar')               # 'print' appends '\n'
...     in_.append('bazquux\n')       # Don't forget trailing '\n'!
...     inp_result = input('?')       # 'bazquux\n' is teed to 'out_' here
...     out_result = out_.getvalue()  # Pull the whole 'out_' stream contents
>>> inp_result
'bazquux'

>>> out_result
'foobar\n?bazquux\n'
```

Note that even though the string appended to `in_` was newline-terminated (otherwise execution would hang), per the [standard behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) `input` stripped that trailing `'\n'` before the string was stored in `inp_result`. As can be seen, the question mark used as the prompt for `input` *is* also stored in `out_`.

However, since `TeeStdin` tees the content read from "`stdin`" *before* it's passed to `input`, `out_` received `?bazquux\n`, not `?bazquux`. While this newline handling has the potential to get somewhat confounded, I'm pretty sure there's not much to be done about it—any twiddles would probably break the transparency of the mock from the perspective of the wrapped code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `subprocess` module to call your script from within python. You can then send test input via `communicate`

```
import subprocess as sp
import sys

interpreter_path = sys.executable
p = sp.Popen([interpreter_path, script_to_test])
(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate(input = testinput)
```

`stdout` and `stderr` can then be tested for correct values