# Send exactly one char to a subprocess' stdin

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to `unittest` a module that gets individual keypresses from stdin. The key-getting code works perfectly, but writing exactly a character (byte?) to a subprocess' stdin is giving me some issues.

I'm using essentially what was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35537867/4532996) with modifications according to the docs and other SO answers:

```
for ch in range(0, 128):
    p = sp.Popen(
        [py, "-u", TEST_HELP, "getch"],
        stdin=sp.PIPE,
        stdout=sp.PIPE,
        stderr=sp.PIPE,
        bufsize=1
    )
    out, err = p.communicate(input=bytes(chr(ch), "ascii"))
    print(out, ",", err)
```

What I want is for `p` to recieve exactly one ASCII character of stdin and then exit. The fact that `ch` is sometimes `NUL`, `EOF` and other control chars is not a problem; it's exactly what I want.

The problem is that this seems to hang doing nothing  until I press <kbd>CTRL - C</kbd>, and then it exits with a keyboard interrupt. The last line of the stack trace is `in selectors.py: fd_event_list = self._poll.poll(timeout)`, which tells me it was waiting for a timeout(?), but I didn't supply the `timeout=int` kwarg.

The command I'm using resolves to `python3 -u helptest.py getch`, which looks like this and which works properly when I run it myself from the command line.

Here's the relevant part of `helptest`:

```
def getch():
    write_and_flush(ord(_ic._Getch()))
```

(`write_and_flush` just runs `stdout.write; stdout.flush`)

and `_ic._Getch()` is:

```
def _Getch():
    if sys.stdin.isatty():
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
            return ch
    else:
        return sys.stdin.read(1)
```

What am I doing wrong in the `subprocess` call that breaks this?

---

Changing the call to:

```
p = sp.Popen(
    [py, TEST_HELP, "getch"],
    stdin=sp.PIPE,
    stdout=sp.PIPE,
    stderr=sp.PIPE,
)
out, err = p.communicate(input=bytes(chr(ch) + "\n", "ascii"))
```

by omitting `bufsize`, removing the `--unbuffered` option, and adding an "EOL" (and variations therein) doesn't/don't change anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The last call to print should have `Flush=True`.

Answer (score -1):

`p.communicate()` code is correct if you want to send a single byte ([ignoring the data corruption that Windows may introduce for the redirected data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33959798/4279)). The issue is your `helptest.py`.

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> behavior indicates that `helptest.py` tries to read from the console directly instead of using `stdin`. It seems that you use [`_Getch()` from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510364/4279) that uses `msvcrt.getch()` on Windows i.e., it may read from the console instead of `stdin`.

Also, `sys.stdin.read(1)` may read more than one byte -- `sys.stdin` is in text mode by default. To read a byte from stdin, you could use `b = os.read(0, 1)` or reopen `sys.stdin` in binary mode e.g., call `sys.stdin.detach()` on Python 3.

If your intent is to read a *key* then use you could [use `readchar` package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25342814/4279). It is better to fix possible (subtle) issues in one place.

Unrelated: bufferring doesn't matter if you use `.communicate()` i.e., you can drop `-u`, `bufsize`. Unless the child process is broken `input=s` should behave similar to `input=s + newline` (i.e., EOF is implicit EOL).

Comment: @cat: no. You most likely have changed something else too. I don't see where you put `Flush=True` and how it may explain the observed behavior.

Comment: I replaced the call to `print` with a call to `write_and_flush` which fixed it. `write_and_flush == print(Flush=True)`

Comment: @cat : 1- your code in the question already uses `write_and_flush()` 2- `flush` should be lowercase 3- it doesn't explain Ctrl+C behavior. The only `print()` that I see is at the end in the parent and it won't hang unless something else is broken.

Answer (score -2):

Your code suggests that you expect `bufsize=1` to set the buffer size to exactly 1, but instead it turns on line-buffered mode. Communication blocks until an EOL was written.

Comment: That hasn't solved it, and no combination of `bufsize` with the `-u`nbuffered option changes anything